# How can I launch Front Panel in CDE (Common Desktop Environment)?

Tags: terminal, solaris

When using Cygwin/X, after I ssh with x11 forwarding into a Solaris 9 system, sometimes I can't see the Front Panel or even the wallpaper:

[image]

Is there a way to bring Front Panel into view, or launch it from the terminal?

The server is has CDE 1.5.7 installed.

Comment: At the screenshot, there's a plain Twm (probably launched via `ttsession`). In order to see CDE (with the panel, wallpaper and `Dtwm` as a window manager), you need to launch `/usr/dt/bin/dtsession`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDE Front Panel is part of the `dtwm` window manager. Run `/usr/dt/bin/dtwm` instead of your current window manager (`twm`, it looks like?) to get the CDE Front Panel.

As someone noted in the comments, normally when using CDE you run the session manager `dtsession` instead of running `dtwm` directly. `dtsession` provides session saving support and other functionality, notably the Color Server, which is the only way I can find to have CDE apps and other Motif apps use the color scheme configured through `dtstyle` rather than the really terrible cyan default.